# Is there a Moles version which support .net framework 4.0

Tags: .net, moles

I've noticed that Moles declares that support VS2010, but the company policy enforces our project uses .net 4.0,  The target framework of the installed Moles is 2.0.

And as I know 2.0 and 4.0 are incompatible version change.

So is there a downloadable moles version which support .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: We use moles to test 4.0, what are the problems you refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moles supports .NET versions 2-4.  Please ensure you have the most current version of Moles.  Moles should work in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, on any supported .NET framework.